# Command line Swift build - This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcrun

I am building a Swift project using the command line. macOS version is 10.14.5, Xcode version is 10.2.1

When trying to run the generated executable I get:
"This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4."

Running "otool -L" on the executable I get:
"...
@rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1001.0.82)
..."

Running "swift --version" I get:
"Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0"

Running "xcrun swift --version" I get:
"Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0"

Any ideas what can be done to run the generated executable ?

Answer (score 1):

I run into same issue. 
Currently can be fixed with specifying target:

```
swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.14"
```